Enhancement when a transfer order is cancelled in LT15
Is there any enhancement to delete an entry from a custom table as soon as a transfer order is cancelled in LT15 when the save button is pressed?

"Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem and searching for existing questions..." (Help Center - How to ask). There are existing answers in the Web: https://www.google.com/search?q=LT15+user+exit+save.
